# Nothing return after input array in class

Tags: php

I'm trying to input value into class array then output that array from class but I get nothing from echo. Thank you for advice.

```
<?php
class Packing{

    public $boxList;    
    public function getBoxlist() {
        return $boxList;
    }

    public function addBox($name,$weightLimit){
        $this->boxList = array($name, $weightLimit);
    }
}
?>

test

<?php
    $package = new Packing();
    $package->addBox("RedBox","30");
    $package->addBox("GreenBox","40");
    echo $package->getBoxlist();
?>
```

Comment: `$boxList` !== `$this->boxList`. Also note that you overwrite the array in every function call.

Comment: then I should return $this->boxList and using input for array ?

Comment: Since you probably want to return the class property and not a local variable, which is not defined, yes you want to return `$this->boxList`. You also probably want to change `$this->boxList` to `$this->boxList[]` in your `addBox()` function, since you probably want to *add* stuff to the array and not overwrite it.

Comment: Thank @Rizier123 that works. ( must change echo though. )

Answer (score 4):

1. It should be like this, use `$this->boxList` instead of `$boxList`

   ```
   public function getBoxlist() {
     return $this->boxList;
   }
   ```
2. You are overwriting `boxList` value
3. its array not text so use `print_r` not `echo`

   ```
   print_r($package->getBoxlist());
   ```

Check here : https://eval.in/752903

---

Demo from https://eval.in/752907

```
<?php
class Packing{

    public $boxList =  array();    
    public function getBoxlist() {
        return $this->boxList;
    }

    public function addBox($name,$weightLimit){
        $this->boxList[] = array($name, $weightLimit);
    }
}
    $package = new Packing();
    $package->addBox("RedBox","30");
    $package->addBox("GreenBox","40");
    print_r($package->getBoxlist());
?>
```

Comment: Thanks , But need to change $this->boxList[] too. Since my intention is too add stuff to array.